# Compound time to simple time

Tags: notation, rhythm, time-signatures

What does a crotchet in 9/8 time turn into when converted into 3/4 time? Also, what does a quaver turn into when converted from 9/8 time to 3/4 time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going from compound to simple, the divisions will alter greatly. You are trying to go from 9/8 to 3/4 so you will be trying to fit 3 notes where 2 should go hence you now need to use triplets for your eighth notes like so:

```
X: 1
M: 9/8
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
GGG GGG GGG|
```

```
X: 1
M: 3/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
(3 GGG (3 GGG (3 GGG|
```

Your quarter notes will be the equivalent of two eighth note triplets and a long short pattern (quarter - eighth) would look like this:

```
X: 1
M: 9/8
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
G2G G2G G2G|
```

```
X: 1
M: 3/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
(3:2:2 G2G (3:2:2 G2G (3:2:2 G2G |
```

Comment: Would the metronome mark be the same for both?

Comment: @Tim The metronome mark would change from dotted-crotchet in 9/8 to crotchet in 3/4, but the value for each of those would be the same.

Comment: I would also include the interpretation of each of the beats becoming a bar of 3/4, as opposed to having each beat represented within a single bar.

Answer (score 0):

My Music teacher suggested to  + or -  triplets and dots. So if you have 3 dotted crotchets (1/4 notes), you take away the dots. In future, if you need to change it the other way round you could start with crotchets (1/4 notes) and add dots.

It's the same with triplets. If you have 3 quavers (1/8 notes), you add triplets. And, once again, if in future you need to change it the other way round, you could start with quavers (1/8 notes) and add triplets.

It's easy once you get the hang of it!

:)